# AutoSize and the Height Attribute

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to auto populate some labels using a loop.

```
Point labelLocation = new Point(5, 15);
// e is an enum passed to the function
// box is a GroupBox passed to the function
foreach(var value in Enum.GetValues(e.GetType()))
{
    Label workingLabel = new Label
    {
        AutoSize = true,
        Location = labelLocation,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
        Text = value.ToString()
    };
    labelLocation = new Point(labelLocation.X, workingLabel.Location.Y + workingLabel.Height);
    box.Controls.Add(workingLabel);
}
```

Whether or not autosize is set, the height always returns 23. So if I set autosize to false, I see borders that are too big, but nicely packed together. If I set it to true, I see borders that are perfect, except there are big gaps in between them.

It seems that the border is not the same as the height of the control, and I'm not sure how to adjust it to make them the same.

Comment: Added some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AutoSize won't happen until the label is added to a container.  So try switching the two lines of code from:

```
labelLocation = new Point(labelLocation.X, workingLabel.Location.Y + workingLabel.Height);
box.Controls.Add(workingLabel);
```

to

```
box.Controls.Add(workingLabel);
labelLocation = new Point(labelLocation.X, workingLabel.Location.Y + workingLabel.Height);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it.